# Pushing onto Mongo SubDoc of SubDoc array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm going around in circles with this one so hoping someone can help. I'm building a nodejs application that receives sensor values from nodes. There can be multiple sensors on a node.

Using NodeJS, Mongod DB and Mongoose, all running on a raspberry pi, 3 I've built the following Schemas & Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var valueSchema = new Schema ({
  timestamp: {type: Date},
  value: {}
});

var sensorSchema = new Schema ({
  id: {type: Number},
  type: {type: String},
  description: {type: String},
  ack: {type: Boolean},
  values: [valueSchema]
});

var SensorNode = mongoose.model('SensorNode', {
  id: {type: Number, required: true},
  protocol: {},
  sensors: [sensorSchema]
});
```

I can add in the node, and push sensors onto the sensors array, but I seem unable to push values onto the values array.

I've looked over a few other examples and questions on similar issues, and looked at using populate, but cant seem to get them to work.

Here is my code:

```
function saveValue(rsender, rsensor, payload) {

  var value = {
    values: {
      timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
      value: payload
    }
  }

  SensorNode.findOneAndUpdate({

    "id": rsender,
    "sensors.id": rsensor
  }, {
    "$push": {
      "sensors.$": value
    }
  }, function(err, result) {

    if (err) { 
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
  });

}
```

This is returning undefined for the result and this error:

```
MongoError: exception: Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array
```

Values is definitely an array in the sensor schema.

I'm using readable ids rather than the auto assigned Mongo DB IDs for the sake of the UI, but I could use the MongoDB _id if that makes any difference, I don't see why it would?

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using positional operator $ so let's check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. To project, or return, an array element from a read operation, see the $ projection operator.

So sensors.$ will return one particular document from your sensors array. That's why you're getting an error. On this level of your document you can only replace this item by using $set. I bet you wanted to do something like this:

```
SensorNode.findOneAndUpdate({

    "id": rsender,
    "sensors.id": rsensor
  }, {
    "$push": {
      "sensors.$.values": payload
    }
  });
```

This operation will just append payload to values array in one particular sensor with id equal to rsensor.

Comment: Ah, you beauty! Thanks mate! One other thing I had to change was to remove the values object from the value variable, just left in the two fields and it worked perfectly. Cheers